# scalar-valued sql function with multiple joins and conditions

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

I've written a function that returns a single value based on multiple conditions across multiple tables.  The function works but I'm looking for a simpler way to get the value.  Below is the logic I used to build the function in a query analyzer to test multiple results.  I thought about using multiple case/when statements in the where clause but couldn't quite get it to work - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
declare
    @cat varchar(10) = 'A1'
    ,@stat varchar(10) = '20'
    ,@level int = 4
    ,@sop varchar(10) = ''
    ,@payid varchar(10) = ''
    ,@paysubid varchar(10) = ''

    declare @out varchar(10) = ''   

-- status match - sop, payid and subid override
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (isnull(a.sourceofpay,'') = @sop and isnull(a.[payid],'') = @payid and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = @paysubid) 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and isnull(c.[status],'') = @stat
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    if @out <> '' 
        begin
            print 'status match - sop, payid and subid override. out value = '+@out
            return
        end

    -- status match - sop only override
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (a.sourceofpay = @sop and isnull(a.[payid],'') = '' and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = '') 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and isnull(c.[status],'') = @stat
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    if @out <> '' 
        begin
            print 'status match - sop override only. out value = '+@out
            return
        end

    -- status match - payid and subid only override
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (isnull(a.sourceofpay,'') = '' and isnull(a.[payid],'') = @payid and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = @paysubid) 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and isnull(c.[status],'') = @stat
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    if @out <> '' 
        begin
            print 'status match - payid and subid override only. out value = '+@out
            return
        end

    -- status match - no overide (default)
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (isnull(a.sourceofpay,'') = '' and isnull(a.[payid],'') = '' and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = '') 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and isnull(c.[status],'') = @stat
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    if @out <> '' 
        begin
            print 'status match - no overide (default).  out value = '+@out
            return
        end

    -- no status match - sop, payid and subid override
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (isnull(a.sourceofpay,'') = @sop and isnull(a.[payid],'') = @payid and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = @paysubid) 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and a.stat277_statusId is null
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    if @out <> '' 
        begin
            print 'no status match - sop, payid and subid override. out value = '+@out
            return
        end

    -- no status match - sop only override
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (a.sourceofpay = @sop and isnull(a.[payid],'') = '' and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = '') 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and a.stat277_statusId is null
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    if @out <> '' 
        begin
            print 'no status match - sop override only. out value = '+@out
            return
        end

    -- no status match - payid and subid only override
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (isnull(a.sourceofpay,'') = '' and isnull(a.[payid],'') = @payid and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = @paysubid) 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and a.stat277_statusId is null
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    if @out <> '' 
        begin
            print 'no status match - payid and subid only override. out value = '+@out
            return
        end

    -- no status match - no overide (default)
    select @out = d.[billedstat]
    from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter] 
    where (isnull(a.sourceofpay,'') = '' and isnull(a.[payid],'') = '' and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = '') 
        and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
        and a.stat277_statusId is null
        and a.[csflevel] = @level

    print 'default '''''
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? That looks more like MS SQL Server code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case statement in the select to cover all of your conditions rather than in the where clause, e.g.

```
select @message = 
   case
     when isnull(a.sourceofpay,'') = @sop
       and isnull(a.[payid],'') = @payid
       and isnull(a.[paysubid],'') = @paysubid
       and isnull(b.[status],'') = @cat 
       and isnull(c.[status],'') = @stat
       and a.[csflevel] = @level then
       'status match - sop, payid and subid override. out value = '
     when ...
     else 'default ''''' end,
  @out = d.billedstat
  from [dbo].[BilledStatusOverride] a
    inner join [dbo].[cat277] b on a.[cat277_statusId] = b.[COUNTER]
    left outer join [dbo].[stat277] c on a.[stat277_statusId] = c.[COUNTER]
    inner join [dbo].[bsname] d on a.[bsname_statId] = d.[counter]
```

Obviously replace ... with your other test conditions. It still isn't particularly nice, but at least it's only a single SQL statement.